# NYA - symfony 2 cache:clear bug

Tags: symfony, caching, acl

This question might seem like all the other questions about the cache-problems.
I read all the other questions and their answers.
It didn't help or I didn't find the correct answer because this internet is full of the 'obvious' problem.

Following is here:

```
user@gobi:~$ app/console cache:clear --env=prod
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rdm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/logs
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/logs
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rdm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/cache/
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/cache/
```

website works

```
user@gobi:~$ app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

website doesn't work (permission errors)

```
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rdm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/logs
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/logs
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rdm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/cache/
root@gobi:~# setfacl -Rm user:www-data:rwx /.../app/cache/
```

website works again

It seems that some files get permissions u:rw, go:- (/.../app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/controller_injectors) and others ug:rw, o:-

It seems the cache:clear overwrites my acl rights (user:www-data:rwx        #effective:r--)

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to offcial installation docs, setting permission via `facl` is done like this:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Have you tried executing this?

Comment: well. the command yields "www-data" as HTTPDUSER, so basically I did that, yes.